# What are good support forums and blogs related to Goldmine CRM?

Tags: windows, crm

What are good support forums and blogs related to Goldmine CRM?

Answer (score 2):

Been a while since I supported Goldmine, but it was my favorite CRM.

Here are three blogs:

http://www.castellcomputers.com/index.php

http://wizard-systems.typepad.com/goldmine/

http://www.thegoldmineblog.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Tek-Tips](http://www.tek-tips.com/threadminder.cfm?pid=868)